# excluding term from results in solr query

Tags: json, solr

I am new to solr. I am in confusion whether to use `q` or `fq`. Assume I have some fields

- state  (possible values: kerala, delhi, west_bengal etc)
- title
- processed_title
- description
- etc

the indexed fileds are `state`, `title`, `processed_title`, `description`

I want results for

`boiler keyword (all matches) in state delhi and also boiler keyword (exclude repair) in kerala`

One solution for this i think

`q=((boiler AND state:delhi) OR (boiler AND -repair AND state:kerala))`

Other solution might be

`q=boiler&fq=(state:gujarat OR (state:kerala AND -processed_title:repair -title:repair -description:repair))`

I have to write json interafe in python for making queries. The JSON may look like (below dictionary is just an example)

`{
  q: 'boiler',
  filter: {
    state: kerala,
    price: [10 TO 100]
  }
}`

My Questions are:

1. is it okay to write everything in `q` or better to use both `q` and `fq` or is there any approach ??
2. If i want to write a json interface api which will be easy way to create queries 1 or 2 or is there any better solution ??

I am using solr 4.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much better to use both q and fq. You put into fq what is used to filter out docs (outcome is binary, either a doc is in or out), and you put in q what you want to search for (this is more gradual, one doc could match all keywords and another one matches only one. If you can put everything in fq, do so, q=* :* is perfectly ok).

Differences are:

- fq does not affect score, just filters out docs. q affect scores
- fq are cached (unless you ask it not to be cached), so, in exchange of a initial penalty, next queries using the same fq will be much faster. This is the biggest deal.

Regarding the json api question, I don't really understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to use fq if your field has a fixed set of values. In your case, state should be in the fq. q is used in the calculation of the solr score. A higher score means a better match. You can read more [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_are_documents_scored).

fq is not used in the calculation of the score. A document in SOLR either has the state kerala or or doesn't.

Say you have three documents in your system.

```
doc1: {'title':'idli idli idli','state':['kerala','karnataka']}
doc2: {'title':'idli','state':['kerala']}
doc3: {'title':'paneer','state':['punjab']}
```

to query for idli and state kerala, you would use

```
q=idli&fq=kerala
```

This is a bit simplistic but Solr would return a higher score for doc1 because it has more instances of the word idli than doc2. fq doesn't(and shouldn't) affect the score. Either a state has idli or it doesn't